# laravel : how to implement php code to laravel framework

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I Have a code 
    **load_data.php**

```
    $sql="select * from siswa where nis='$_POST[parent_id]'";
    $response = array(); menjadi JSON
    $query = mysql_query($sql);     
    if($query){
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){

                $response[] = $row; 
            }
        }else{
            $response['error'] = 'Data kosong'; data kosong
        }
    }else{
        $response['error'] = mysql_error(); // memberi respon ketika query salah
    }
    die(json_encode($response));
```

?>

how to implement php code above to laravel framework, I tried it and this is bad :

```
public function getLoaddata ($parent_id) {

$siswa = Siswa::Where('id','=',$parent_id)->get();
$response = array();
$query = mysql_query($siswa);
if($query){
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){

                $response[] = $row; 
            }
        }else{
            $response['error'] = 'Data kosong';   data kosong
        }
    }else{
        $response['error'] = mysql_error();  
    }
    die(json_encode($response));  

return View::make('admin/siswa/', compact('siswa'));
```

}

I Wanna make jquery auto input data, I Have java script code like this

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nis").keyup(function() {
        var nisp = $('#nis').val();     
        $.post('load_data.php', // request ke file load_data.php
        {parent_id: nisp},
        function(data){
             $('#nama').val(data[0].nama);
             $('#alamat').val(data[0].alamat);
             $('#biaya').val(data[0].biaya_spp);          
        },'json'
      );
   });
   });
  </script>
```

**what needs to be changed??**

Answer (score 0):

auto create json

```
    <?php

public function SiswaController extends Controller
{
    public function getLoadData($id)
    {
        // return dari Eloquent, array, atau collection
        // otomatis menjadi JSON
        return Siswa::where('id', $id)->get();
    }
}
```